Getting ValidationError when trying to inspect the message traceback of LangGraph with checkpointer
I'm trying to build a LangGraph application with MemorySaver() to retain memory in between interactions. I've been following the official documentation "Part 3: Adding Memory to the Chatbot" but I've added in a system prompt to guide the flow of the chatbot since I am using tools.
Here is the full flow of my GraphBuilder
    def create_prompt():
    return (ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            (
                "system",
                converser_prompt.format(cols = cols),
            ),
            MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history"),
                ("human", "{input}")
        ]
    ))

    memory = MemorySaver()
    
    class State(TypedDict):
    messages: Annotated[list, add_messages]
    

    graph_builder = StateGraph(State)

    llm_with_tools = llm.bind_tools(tools)

    def chatbot(state: State):
    user_input = state["messages"]

    prompt_template = create_prompt()
    formatted_prompt = prompt_template.format(
        chat_history=state["messages"][:-1],
        input=user_input
    )

    response = llm_with_tools.invoke(formatted_prompt)
    state["messages"].append({"role": "assistant", "content": response})

    return {"messages": state["messages"]}
    
    graph_builder.add_node("chatbot", chatbot)

    tool_node = ToolNode(tools=tools)
    graph_builder.add_node("tools", tool_node)
    
    graph_builder.add_conditional_edges(
        "chatbot",
        tools_condition,
    )
    # Any time a tool is called, we return to the chatbot to decide the next step
    graph_builder.add_edge("tools", "chatbot")
    graph_builder.add_edge(START, "chatbot")

    graph = graph_builder.compile(checkpointer=memory)


After I compile the graph with memory I then follow the testing code they have provided to check it
user_input = "Hi there! My name is Will."

# The config is the **second positional argument** to stream() or invoke()!
events = graph.stream(
    {"messages": [("user", user_input)]}, config, stream_mode="values"
)
for event in events:
    event["messages"][-1].pretty_print()

which gives me the following error:
================================ Human Message =================================

Hi there! My name is Will.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_43584\1084556082.py in <module>
      5     {"messages": [("user", user_input)]}, config, stream_mode="values"
      6 )
----> 7 for event in events:
      8     event["messages"][-1].pretty_print()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langgraph\pregel\__init__.py in stream(self, input, config, stream_mode, output_keys, interrupt_before, interrupt_after, debug, subgraphs)
   1654                 # with channel updates applied only at the transition between steps
   1655                 while loop.tick(input_keys=self.input_channels):
-> 1656                     for _ in runner.tick(
   1657                         loop.tasks.values(),
   1658                         timeout=self.step_timeout,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langgraph\pregel\runner.py in tick(self, tasks, reraise, timeout, retry_policy, get_waiter)
    165             t = tasks[0]
    166             try:
--> 167                 run_with_retry(
    168                     t,
    169                     retry_policy,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langgraph\pregel\retry.py in run_with_retry(task, retry_policy, configurable)
     38             task.writes.clear()
     39             # run the task
---> 40             return task.proc.invoke(task.input, config)
     41         except ParentCommand as exc:
     42             ns: str = config[CONF][CONFIG_KEY_CHECKPOINT_NS]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langgraph\utils\runnable.py in invoke(self, input, config, **kwargs)
    408                     input = step.invoke(input, config, **kwargs)
    409                 else:
--> 410                     input = step.invoke(input, config)
    411         # finish the root run
    412         except BaseException as e:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langgraph\utils\runnable.py in invoke(self, input, config, **kwargs)
    182         else:
    183             context.run(_set_config_context, config)
--> 184             ret = context.run(self.func, input, **kwargs)
    185         if isinstance(ret, Runnable) and self.recurse:
    186             return ret.invoke(input, config)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langgraph\graph\graph.py in _route(self, input, config, reader, writer)
     86     ) -> Runnable:
     87         if reader:
---> 88             value = reader(config)
     89             # passthrough additional keys from node to branch
     90             # only doable when using dict states

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langgraph\pregel\read.py in do_read(config, select, fresh, mapper)
    105             return mapper(read(select, fresh))
    106         else:
--> 107             return read(select, fresh)
    108 
    109 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langgraph\pregel\algo.py in local_read(step, checkpoint, channels, managed, task, config, select, fresh)
    187             skip_context=True,
    188         ) as (local_channels, _):
--> 189             apply_writes(copy_checkpoint(checkpoint), local_channels, [task], None)
    190             values = read_channels({**channels, **local_channels}, select)
    191     else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langgraph\pregel\algo.py in apply_writes(checkpoint, channels, tasks, get_next_version)
    291     for chan, vals in pending_writes_by_channel.items():
    292         if chan in channels:
--> 293             if channels[chan].update(vals) and get_next_version is not None:
    294                 checkpoint["channel_versions"][chan] = get_next_version(
    295                     max_version,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langgraph\channels\binop.py in update(self, values)
     86             values = values[1:]
     87         for value in values:
---> 88             self.value = self.operator(self.value, value)
     89         return True
     90 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langgraph\graph\message.py in add_messages(left, right)
     70     left = [
     71         message_chunk_to_message(cast(BaseMessageChunk, m))
---> 72         for m in convert_to_messages(left)
     73     ]
     74     right = [

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\messages\utils.py in convert_to_messages(messages)
    355     if isinstance(messages, PromptValue):
    356         return messages.to_messages()
--> 357     return [_convert_to_message(m) for m in messages]
    358 
    359 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\messages\utils.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    355     if isinstance(messages, PromptValue):
    356         return messages.to_messages()
--> 357     return [_convert_to_message(m) for m in messages]
    358 
    359 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\messages\utils.py in _convert_to_message(message)
    328             )
    329             raise ValueError(msg) from e
--> 330         _message = _create_message_from_message_type(
    331             msg_type, msg_content, **msg_kwargs
    332         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\messages\utils.py in _create_message_from_message_type(message_type, content, name, tool_call_id, tool_calls, id, **additional_kwargs)
    261         message: BaseMessage = HumanMessage(content=content, **kwargs)
    262     elif message_type in ("ai", "assistant"):
--> 263         message = AIMessage(content=content, **kwargs)
    264     elif message_type in ("system", "developer"):
    265         if message_type == "developer":

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\messages\ai.py in __init__(self, content, **kwargs)
    177             kwargs: Additional arguments to pass to the parent class.
    178         """
--> 179         super().__init__(content=content, **kwargs)
    180 
    181     @classmethod

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\messages\base.py in __init__(self, content, **kwargs)
     74             kwargs: Additional fields to pass to the
     75         """
---> 76         super().__init__(content=content, **kwargs)
     77 
     78     @classmethod

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\load\serializable.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    123     def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
    124         """"""
--> 125         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    126 
    127     @classmethod

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.py in __init__(self, **data)
    212         # `__tracebackhide__` tells pytest and some other tools to omit this function from tracebacks
    213         __tracebackhide__ = True
--> 214         validated_self = self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=self)
    215         if self is not validated_self:
    216             warnings.warn(

ValidationError: 21 validation errors for AIMessage
content.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=AIMessage(content='Hello ...o': 0, 'reasoning': 0}}), input_type=AIMessage]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/string_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].0.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=('content', 'Hello Will! ...tions or patient data?'), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/string_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].0.dict[any,any]
  Input should be a valid dictionary [type=dict_type, input_value=('content', 'Hello Will! ...tions or patient data?'), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/dict_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].1.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=('additional_kwargs', {'refusal': None}), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/string_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].1.dict[any,any]
  Input should be a valid dictionary [type=dict_type, input_value=('additional_kwargs', {'refusal': None}), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/dict_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].2.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=('response_metadata', {'t...top', 'logprobs': None}), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/string_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].2.dict[any,any]
  Input should be a valid dictionary [type=dict_type, input_value=('response_metadata', {'t...top', 'logprobs': None}), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/dict_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].3.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=('type', 'ai'), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/string_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].3.dict[any,any]
  Input should be a valid dictionary [type=dict_type, input_value=('type', 'ai'), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/dict_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].4.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=('name', None), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/string_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].4.dict[any,any]
  Input should be a valid dictionary [type=dict_type, input_value=('name', None), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/dict_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].5.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=('id', 'run-b6e9b042-8e95...c9-8daf-0d1584bd5cbb-0'), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/string_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].5.dict[any,any]
  Input should be a valid dictionary [type=dict_type, input_value=('id', 'run-b6e9b042-8e95...c9-8daf-0d1584bd5cbb-0'), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/dict_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].6.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=('example', False), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/string_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].6.dict[any,any]
  Input should be a valid dictionary [type=dict_type, input_value=('example', False), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/dict_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].7.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=('tool_calls', []), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/string_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].7.dict[any,any]
  Input should be a valid dictionary [type=dict_type, input_value=('tool_calls', []), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/dict_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].8.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=('invalid_tool_calls', []), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/string_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].8.dict[any,any]
  Input should be a valid dictionary [type=dict_type, input_value=('invalid_tool_calls', []), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/dict_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].9.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=('usage_metadata', {'inpu...o': 0, 'reasoning': 0}}), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/string_type
content.list[union[str,dict[any,any]]].9.dict[any,any]
  Input should be a valid dictionary [type=dict_type, input_value=('usage_metadata', {'inpu...o': 0, 'reasoning': 0}}), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.10/v/dict_type

I tried to iterate through events and just print the result instead:
for event in events:
    print(event)

Which gave me this output:
{'messages': [HumanMessage(content='Hi there! My name is Will.', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}, id='c4baa915-7647-4682-b106-2c4ba2932192'), HumanMessage(content='Remember my name?', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}, id='c97716f8-b480-4c13-b7f4-5c786510bd70'), HumanMessage(content='Hi there! My name is Will.', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}, id='00a05be8-2a84-40b5-9158-691d2c4fce85'), HumanMessage(content='Hi there! My name is Will.', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}, id='94e69a2e-b809-4c6a-903d-968ebc26cc91')]}

but also the same ValidationError as before
I also tried to inspect the documentation for stream() and astream() in LangGraph but I am not sure what to return to get the correct output from the graph. If I could have some guidance as to where my error lies (I'm guessing it's to do with the ChatPromptTemplate as that's the main variation in my code compared to the documentation) it would be really helpful - so that I can figure out how to get the response output in my application. Thanks!
